# Prolog | Can I continue execution after a false?

Tags: prolog

Using prolog, can I continue execution after a line returns false?

I have to create a tic-tac-toe game.  I want to check for a winning state after each player's turn.

checkwin returns true when there is a winning state, but false otherwise. The issue then is that after it returns false, I can't move on to the next player's move.

How can I check it every turn, and continue to execute the code that follows the check?  Is there a way to 'continue if false'?

```
adjustGame(PosX, PosY, Gameboard, Token) :-
    update(PosX, PosY, Gameboard, Newboard, Token),
    display(Newboard),
    checkwin(Newboard,Token),% This is false until the game has a winner
    play(Newboard,Token).    % but I want to execute this line until then

checkwin([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],T) :-
    same(A,B,C,T);
    same(D,E,F,T);
    same(G,H,I,T);
    same(A,D,G,T);
    same(B,E,H,T);
    same(C,F,I,T);
    same(A,E,I,T);
    same(C,E,G,T).

same(X,X,X,X).
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [`ignore/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=ignore%2f1).

Comment: What's the context in which `adjustGame/4` is called? You could use `((checkwin(...) -> true ; play(...))`, but then you lose the choice point before this call, and I'm not sure if you need it. I suspect the logic might need to be refactored a little to achieve what you want.

Comment: Of interest: [Tic-Tac-Toe](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/03sp/slides/PrologEx/tictactoe.pl.txt) in Prolog.

Comment: Of interest: [Generate and Test](http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws0708/logic/prolog9.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disjunction is the `;` operator:

```
?- false ; X=3.
X = 3.
```

Think of it of *if-else* - if `false` then `false` else `X=3`:

```
?- true ; X=3.
true

?- check_win(...) ; play_game(...).
...
```

There also is a full-fledge *if-then-else*:

```
?- true -> X=4 ; X=3. 
X = 4.

?- false -> X=4 ; X=3.
X = 3.

?- check_win(...) -> writeln("WIN"); play_game(...).
...
```

Comment: It should be noted that `-> ... ; ...` eliminates the choice point before that expression, so it's an important consideration before using it.

Comment: Fantastic.  Worked for me.  As @lurker suggested, I had to change the logic a little too.  Thanks, all.